# Background colour of <div> containing <ul>

Tags: html, css, navigation, html-lists, background-color

I've created a horizontal navigation menu in HTML using `<ul>` and inline-block display styling. I'm wanting to set the background colour of the containing `<div>`, but it isn't working. It's as though the `<div>` isn't wrapping around the `<ul>`.

The first `<div>` is supposed to set the background colour for the entire width of that part of the page. The second `<div>` then sets the width of the navigation menu within that area, and centres the `<div>` so that the unused space is evenly distributed either side.

Here's the code:

```
<div style="background-color: #302683">
    <div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 80%">
        <ul style="padding: 0; margin: 0">
            <li style="display: inline-block; float: left"><a href="#design" title="Design" style="text-decoration: none; color: #FFFFFF; display: inline-block; text-align: center; padding: 20px">Design</a></li>
            <li style="display: inline-block; float: left"><a href="#proofreading" title="Proofreading" style="text-decoration: none; color: #FFFFFF; display: inline-block; text-align: center; padding: 20px">Proofreading</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, how would I centre the `<ul>` within the second `<div>`, so that the `<li>`s appear in the centre?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should work: `<div style="background-color: #302683; overflow: hidden;">`

See the example: http://jsfiddle.net/b8q836zs/1/

> Overflow: hidden|auto will make an element establish a 'new block
>   formatting context' — an isolated container, which will keep it from
>   flowing into the space occupied by preceiding floats — see: [CSS 2.1 -
>   floats](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats).